# confirmation message on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am working on a calendar and i have a list of calendars, each one having its own id.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="calendar in calendars">
        <em>{{calendar.calendar_name}}</em>
        <a ng-click="deleteCalendar({{calendar.calendar_id}})">Delete</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now this deletes me a calendar. But now i want to create a custom overlay to ask me "Are you sure you want to delete this calendar?" and a Yes and No buttons. Is there an easy way to do this without using the confirmation standard message that javascript provides ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a hidden div that's styled the way you want (probably fixed positioning), then have a function show it when the user clicks the delete button. Then the custom confirmation button in there can reference deleteCalendar().

Comment: can i somehow use defer on a confirmation overlay ?